# Jenkins 'load' works fine and then on the very next line is undefined. How is this possible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a simple example where I am trying to load a groovy script - for reasons I will post in another unrelated discussion, I am trying to determine there owner and binding of `load`. I can `load` this `gradlew` groovy script fine, but literally the very next line I get an error about how there is no such property `load` - and that's just blowing my mind. It's int he exact same scope so resolution should be identical. Ultimately I am trying to determine where `load` is bound to so I can replace it with my own definition (you can disagree or yell at me in another post coming shortly).

**My question:** Where is `load` actually defined? And why is it suddenly out of scope 1 line later?

```
node('java') {

    stage('SCM') {
        checkout scm
    }

    def gradlew = load('pipeline/gradle/gradlew.groovy')
    println("owner is ${load}") // error
    stage('experiment') {
        println(this.class.package)
        println(this.class.with{ [it.methods,it.declaredMethods]}.flatten()*.name.sort().unique().join('\n'))
        println(this.getBinding())
        println(this.binding.variables)
    }


}
```

produces:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (pipeline/gradle/gradlew.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: load for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:348)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:15)
```

Comment: Nope. That's a script. I know precisely what it is. I wanted to know where the closure that `load` is was defined.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand one important fact - `load` is a Jenkins pipeline step. It comes with `workflow-cps` plugin, and here is its [source code file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/steps/LoadStep.java).

The pipeline steps are similar to methods (think of it as a method for simplicity), and thus they get executed as methods. For instance:

```
def gradlew = load('pipeline/gradle/gradlew.groovy')
```

In this line, you execute `load` step with an argument and you assign loaded script object to a `gradlew` variable. So if your script defines a method `def foo(int x)` you can execute it with

```groovy
gradlew.foo(42)
```

The error you get is descriptive. It says:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: load for class: WorkflowScript
```

It gets thrown because you are trying to use `load` step as it was a class field or a local variable, which is not correct. You can access a result of the `load` step method execution, which means you can print the `gradlew` variable:

```
println("owner is ${gradlew}")
```

Comment: I was using `load` on the assumption that it was a closure and thus would have properties like an owner. I wanted it to print it `toString` method to the console so I could know more about it. Everything has a type in Java including a primitive and `load` must be an object.  Since I setup this post I have read some more and I think I can my bigger question answered anyways. For the record: I don't care about `gradlew` - that's a script object.

Comment: You are right though: I did misunderstand some things.